# GmailApp.sendEmail() doesn't parse plain text when sending HTML mail. How can I make it to show plain text?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, html-email

I have a document with email body content. I am using Apps Script to fetch the document from URL and send it as an HTML mail.

```
var url = "address of the document";
var param = {method      : "get",
             headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " +ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}, muteHttpExceptions:true,
    };

var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
MailApp.sendEmail(
        emailId,       // recipient
        tempSubject,          // subject 
        body,
        {                    // body
          htmlBody: html,  // advanced options
        });
```

However, if my document has text like this for example:

```
Hi 

username: rml@gmail.com
password : <aSrD9nn

Happy browsing!
```

In the resultant email, the text after `password:` is blank. It does not show in the mail body of the email sent. Apparently, it considers `<` as an opening tag, I think.

Is there a way to solve this? I tried with other text and it works fine.

How do I overcome this problem? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just send it as plain text?

Comment: Because I will be adding many more links and elements to the document and eventually will need html email to be sent.

Comment: You need to test text for `<` and convert it to `&lt;` It's better to create the html yourself by getting text from the document.